# Floating Action Button not showing fully inside a fragment in Android-Design_library 22.2.0

Tags: android-design-library

This Fragment is an instance of a TabViewPager. I am having a issue with the FAB button.  Now the problem that I am facing is the FAB button is not fully visible. Its half of the portion is hidden as shown in the screenshot below. Can any one help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLwOs.png)

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMqsm.png)

my activity_main.xml

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_below="@id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

     </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

my Fragment_activity file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:id="@+id/fabBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:backgroundTint="#C2185B"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: did you solve the issue.?

Comment: i think it is fixed in recent version of support library.